# Log4net log message to Documentdb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, log4net-configuration

I have used relational database with Log4Net to log message using Log4Net Configuration.
I am not sure how to configure and use Document Db ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can wrap your log messages as JSON documents and persist. You can use any of the SDK's available in .NET, Java, Node.js or Python or there are REST API's available to perform CRUD operations in DocDB.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sdk-dotnet/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn781481.aspx

Comment: The OP is not soliciting opinions on what is "the better way."